Model to output a formula that describe relationship between probability of Event A and multiple variables
I am fairly new to predictive models and I encounter a problem with a project. I need to express probability of Event A occurring as a function of four to six variables.
End Goal: Probability of Event A~ function of X1, X2, X3, X4, X5
*It needs to be an actual formula (not blackbox) because i need to subsequently apply the formula to a large volume of data points.
I have the following data available for the Python model to learn and derive the relationship.
Data Format: Column A: data number; Column B: X1 (integer with range 1-120) Column C: X2 (integer with range 1-75) Column D: X3 (decimals with range 0-1) Column E: X4 (decimals with range 0-1) Column F: X5 (time variable with range 0-120) Column G: Event status (0- has yet to happen; 1- happened)
The relationship between probability of Event A and variables are pretty unclear, it may not be linear. But basically i need a python model to learn from data and give me an explicit formula that can calculate this probability.
I am considering multi target regression model and multivariate GLM but I am not sure which one does the job better. Or is there a better Python model out there? (maybe random forest)
Also, appreciate instruction on how to build the Python model you recommend? Help a lost soul thankssss!!!
